# How do I move past the ICS lock screen using a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: lock-screens, bluetooth, external-keyboard

How do I move past the ICS lock screen using a bluetooth keyboard? Or, alternately, what happens to the keystrokes I type while the lock screen is active? They're different versions of the same question, so I ask them together.